# Cannot filter the data from the MongoDB with respective to the parmas that I give

Tags: reactjs, express

[image]I'm trying to filter the array from the MongoDB with respective to the params I recieve in expressjs.

This is the frontend code where I'm sending the params whic is recieved in the backend fine.

```
 const category = location.pathname
        .toString()
        .substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetCategory(category);
```

And This is the express.js code

```
export const getCategory = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const { category } = req.params;
        const foundCategory = await Blog.find({ blogCategory: category });
        if (!foundCategory)
          return res.status(200).json({ message: "No blogs in this category" });
        res.status(200).json({ data: foundCategory });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: `${error.message}` });
      }
    };
```

I'm getting the whole data which are present in that model, not specifically that matches the params.

I want to get the data that matches the blogCategory value. I've also added the image of my blog collection

Comment: the reason might be your category value same for all docs in your mongodb. are you sure it's different for all docs or for some at least?

Comment: All are different only @GulshanAggarwal

Comment: did you check the filter you applied { blogCategory: category } here blogCategory key is same as in your db. Also check the value you are passing of category is correct data type(same as in your db).

Comment: Yes, I've also attached the db collection image above. Can you please look at it ?

Comment: what is the value of category for example you are sending?